# can't install or uninstall Heroku on ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, ruby, heroku

I am trying to run heroku on my terminal  with `heroku login` command but everytime it show me this message

```
Install the Heroku CLI from https://cli.heroku.com
```

If i do `heroku -v` , `heroku run rails c` in all command it show me this same error

@ubuntu18.04 I perfomed below steps

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

heroku is already the newest version (7.9.3-1).
```

after this

```
heroku -v

Install the Heroku CLI from https://cli.heroku.com
```

Please help me to find solution about it.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` for the installtion? Or just a installation in the user home? Try `which heroku`

Comment: Why didn't install it like this `sudo snap install --classic heroku`

Comment: it show me "snap "heroku" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'" and then i checked heroku -v => rbenv: heroku: command not found

The `heroku' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.3.0
  2.3.6